# how to apply two different queries in different dates php

Tags: php

i have a table like this

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              seeker                             |
+----+-------+----------+---------------+-------------------------+
| id | name  | password | register_date | login_date | limit_date |
+----+-------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+
| 01 | ali   |   ****   |  2012-02-08   | 2012-02-09 | 2012-03-09 |
| 02 | hamza |   ****   |  2012-04-10   | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |
| 03 | sam   |   ****   |  2012-04-15   | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |
+----+-------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+

register_date = when user ger registered
login-date= when user attempt to login
limit date= login-date + 1 month
```

now i have to apply two different delete query 
one for user who register and login "ali"
one for user who only register but didnot attempt to login "hamza, sam" and have login-date='0000-00-00'

i am using `if-statment` like this

```
 $qry="select * from seeker where login_date='0000-00-00'";
    $rs= mysql_query($qry, $con);
    $res=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

    if($res==0)
    {
      //query to delete user who has login date
      $q= "delete from seeker where current_date = limit_date'";
      if($rq=mysql_query($q, $con));
      echo "$q";

    }

   else if($res!=0)
    {
        //query to delete user who didnot login and has login-date='0000-00-00'
        $qry1="delete from seeker where '$days' >= 30";
            $rs1= mysql_query($qry1, $con);
            echo $qry1;
    }
```

i am very confused and `making some mistake in if-statment` i guess. 
when i run this code it executes only `else if` . it should also execute `first if` because both conditions occurs according to my database

Comment: i am new here and i thought to accept the answer you only need to "up-vote" answer. i just came to know how to accept the answer by checking "tick" :)

Comment: i will accept your answer if it will helpful for me..

Comment: thank you @WouterJ for formating my table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i guess u wanted to retrieve the number of rows so :

```
 $qry="select * from seeker where login_date='0000-00-00'";
    $rs= mysql_query($qry, $con);
    $res=mysql_num_rows($rs);

    if($res==0)
    {
      //query to delete user who has login date
      $q= "delete from seeker where current_date = limit_date'";
      if($rq=mysql_query($q, $con));
      echo "$q";

    }

   else if($res!=0)
    {
        //query to delete user who didnot login and has login-date='0000-00-00'
        $qry1="delete from seeker where '$days' >= 30";
            $rs1= mysql_query($qry1, $con);
            echo $qry1;
    }
```

EDIT :

```
<?php

    $qry="select * from seeker where login_date='0000-00-00'";
    $rs= mysql_query($qry, $con);
    $res=mysql_num_rows($rs);


    if($res!=0)
    {
        $qry1="delete from seeker where '$days' >= 30";
            $rs1= mysql_query($qry1, $con);
            echo $qry1;
    }

    $qry="select * from seeker where current_date = limit_date";
    $rs= mysql_query($qry, $con);
    $res=mysql_num_rows($rs);

    if($res!=0)
    {
         $q= "delete from seeker where current_date = limit_date";
            $rs1= mysql_query($qry1, $con);
            echo $qry1;
    }

?>
```

Comment: @yassine-hell i am facing same problem 1 want to run both queries but this only runs `else-if`

Comment: @maham well i guess u did not understand the if statement, 
if (the condition is true) { 
     execute this code; 
}
else { 
      execute this code; 
} 

and in ur example its executing the second code, because $res is not equal to zero.
if u wanted to run both queries same time u should get rid of the else if statment